# Replace Add to cart with pop up Contact form

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us

I wanted to change all add to cart button to open a Popup contact form which will be pre-filled with product details and send the email to the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need to create pop ownself.I will give you how to call contacts us form at product view page by below code

```
<?php   $this->getLayout()->getCreateBlock('catalog/product_view')
->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('cotacts/index/post') )->setTemplate('contacts/productform.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Here I  create a template file `productform.phtml` which is replicate of default `contacts>form.phtml file`.

On your `productform.phtml` file  you can get product data by

```
<?php 
// get full model
$_product = $this->getProduct();
echo $_product->getName();
 ?>
```

Now you can update your form basic of above details.